# Project not appearing in Eclipse's explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java programming.
Until now, all I was doing was writing the code on eclipse and running the code there only.
However this time i tried to write a code in text editor and run the same through following:

1. I created a folder named `TEMP3` in workspace. (I could see as well the folders of other projects that I directly created on eclipse.)
2. Created a `hello.java` file in text editor which outputs "Hello world" and saved that file in the folder `TEMP3` created above.
3. Now I successfully compiled and run the file.
4. Now when I open eclipse, I expect to see the `TEMP3` Project (and in there the hello class) in eclipse's Package Explorer.

But I don't see the `TEMP3` folder.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to import your new folder "TEMP3" and then it should appears.

I'm studying java from middle february 2017 and I can suggest you to use a correct package structure with right names. It helps a lot during programming.

Comment: Eclipse won't recognize this as a project so this won't work.

Comment: Thanks mate for your advice ,you are right.BTW even i started JAVA in  mid feb.

Comment: I started programming Java exactly in the same month. Middle February! I'm studying it every day. I suggest you to use NetBeans 8.2 IDE. In my opinion is better than Eclipse.
I used Eclipse for C++ programming, it was a trouble to set up and configure. NetBeans is my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse projects must contain at least a `.project` file for Eclipse to recognize them as a project. The folder you have created doesn't contain this file so it isn't recognized.

In addition to this Eclipse won't recognize a project added to the workspace externally until you do a 'File > Refresh'.

So the best bet is to create a Java project inside Eclipse in the normal way and then use 'Import > File System' to import the hello.java file.

Note that the Eclipse Package and Project Explorers normally hide the .project file so you don't see it in Eclipse. In addition on Linux and macOS the OS doesn't show files starting with '.'